# Kotlin tests fail from command line with ClassNotFoundException but work from IntelliJ

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, gradle, kotlin

I've a Kotlin Spring Boot project [here](https://github.com/asarkar/spring/tree/master/license-report-kotlin). It has some tests, which run just fine from IntelliJ, but when I run from command line, fail with the following errors.

```
BUILD FAILED in 1m 12s
7 actionable tasks: 7 executed
asarkar:license-report-kotlin$ ./gradlew clean test

> Task :compileKotlin
Using kotlin incremental compilation

> Task :compileTestKotlin
Using kotlin incremental compilation

> Task :test

2017-07-16 21:43:06.345  INFO 2956 --- [      Thread-13] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@54fa5525: startup date [Sun Jul 16 21:42:04 PDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
org.abhijitsarkar.ApplicationTest > testEndToEnd FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError at ApplicationTest.kt:83

org.abhijitsarkar.service.GradleAgentTest > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

org.abhijitsarkar.service.JGitAgentTest > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

org.abhijitsarkar.service.LinkVerifierTest > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

4 tests completed, 4 failed


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

What I've tried so far:

1. Went back and forth between the `build.gradle` and `build.gradle.kts`.
2. Added the Kotlin runtime to the jar `kotlinOptions.includeRuntime = true`.
3. Changed package level functions to functions in an object.

What I found weird:

1. An `out` directory is created in addition to the usual Gradle `build` directory.
2. Some classes/objects are compiled to class files with names ending in `Kt`. I've not found any rhyme or reason for this, but I'm still new to Kotlin, so I may be missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tests (or the actual tested classes) does something strange: They delete somehow the content of the `build` folder which contains the test-classes.

To see this, try the following:

```
./gradlew clean testClasses
find build    # You get a full list of all main and test classes
./gradlew clean testClasses test
find build    # You get a very limited list of resources in the build-folder (must be somehow modified by your code)
```

If you deactivate all your tests and just add the following (just for testing purpose) in there:

```
import io.kotlintest.matchers.*
import io.kotlintest.specs.*

class MyTests : StringSpec() {
  init {

    "length should return size of string" {
      "hello".length shouldBe 5
    }

  }
}
```

If you again gradle-test it,

```
./gradlew clean testClasses test
find build    # all resources again available
```

Check your tests for the problem.

Comment: You're right. My project clones a remote repo and then builds it, and in the process it was somehow deleting the contents of the `build` dir.